# Recipe for Imperial Red Ale?

Tags: recipe, red-ale

If I want to make a red ale in the vein of Lagunitas's Imperial Red, Dry Hopped St. Rogue Red, or Green Flash Hop Head Red. Anyone have any recipes for me? I'm not looking for a traditional Irish red.

Comment: Not ignoring you, just don't have anything to share with you.

Comment: Not ignoring your question, I just don't have anything like this to share!

Comment: Also interested, after I thought about the idea for a while :)

Comment: This question is a little too broad.

Comment: Cleaning up tags: Changed redale to red-ale

Answer (score 3):

There are two that come to mind. The first is Jamil's Evil Twin, which is available in his book Brewing Classic Styles.  The second one is Fire in the Hole, available in both extract and all-grain versions from Morebeer.com.  I've brewed it, and found it to be very close to Lagunitas' Imperial Red, Pizza Port's Shark Attack, and Pike's Tandem Double -- all delicious Imperial Reds.  The only adjustment I would make to the Fire in the Hole recipe is to delete the oak chips -- it tastes fine, but none of the 3 I mentioned use oak.  See my version and recipe at http://huningtonsachsbrauerei.blogspot.com/2009/11/firebreaks.html  It's a mini-mash/extract version.

Comment: This looks good, and this is the answer I would probably select, unfortunately I can't figure out how to get into the somehow unregistered WhatsBillDoing account that I asked this question under.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a recipe that might work. The IBUs are about right, and the grain bill looks solid. I'll have to experiment to see if I can convert it into a mash-extract recipe.

[http://www.brewtility.com/ViewRecipe.aspx?recipeID=3][1]

Oddly, I'm answering my own question through a different account of the same name. Splendid.

Comment: Be sure to post if you get it converted to an extract recipe.